# Import multiple text file to access database

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net

The question of how to import multiple text files into the database table and update  the database without duplicate record based on the date and time :-

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim con As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Student.mdb;Persist Security Info=True")
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Class] SELECT * FROM [Text;DATABASE=C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication10\WebApplication10\App_Data;].[Class.txt]")

    con.Open()
    With cmd
        .Connection = con
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("File Imported Successfully")
    End With
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

In your Access database table Class make sure that the field that contains the date and time field is the primary key. This will prevent importing duplicate entries into the table Class.

Comment: Thanks noted what about import muliple text files using same code, I don't want to use more than one code for each file imported is there any way to import all files? Or should I write a code for each file separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily import all text files into separate Access tables, or import all text files into one single Access table (assuming the schema is the same for each and every file in your folder of interest).

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Call DoImport
End Sub

Function DoImport()

 Dim strPathFile As String
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim strPath As String
 Dim strTable As String
 Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

 ' Change this next line to True if the first row in CSV worksheet
 ' has field names
 blnHasFieldNames = True

 ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
 ' contains the CSV files
 strPath = "C:\your_path_here\"

 ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
 ' the data are to be imported

 strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.txt")

 Do While Len(strFile) > 0
       strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)
       strPathFile = strPath & strFile

       'DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
       DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

 ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
 ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
 '       Kill strPathFile

       strFile = Dir()
 Loop

End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
        Dim strTable As String, strBrowseMsg As String
        Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

        ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
        ' has field names
        blnHasFieldNames = False

        strBrowseMsg = "Select the folder that contains the CSV files:"

        strPath = "C:\your_path_here\"

        If strPath = "" Then
              MsgBox "No folder was selected.", vbOK, "No Selection"
              Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
        ' the data are to be imported
        strTable = "tablename"

        strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.txt")
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
              strPathFile = strPath & "\" & strFile

        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

        ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
        ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
        '       Kill strPathFile

              strFile = Dir()
        Loop
End Sub
```